# Export data from Azure SQL managed instance to Azure Data Lake Storage as json

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a requirement to export data from Azure SQL managed instance to data lake storage as json documents. I have to use SQL Server Integration Services to accomplish this. I tried using the Flexible File Destination Data Flow task but when I see the supported file formats there's no json being supported. What other options do I have to accomplish this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Factory support data movement between Azure Managed Instance and Data lake account, but unfortunately when the destination is Azure Data Lake storage it also doesn't support JSON format using SSIS.

[Azure Data Lake Store Destination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/azure-data-lake-store-destination?view=sql-server-ver15)

> The Azure Data Lake Store Destination component enables an SSIS
> package to write data to an Azure Data Lake Store. **The supported file
> formats are: Text, Avro, and ORC.**

**Workaround:** The possible workaround you can try to use Data Flow activity in Azure Data Factory. Load the data from Managed Instance and transform it using Pivot transformation and store the processed data in Data Lake. This approach doesn't involve SSIS. Check this similar kind of request and approach [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/597960/azure-data-factory-aggregating-sql-rows-into-json.html).

Comment: Hey @pbj!, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?